# problems to set a data frame using dplyr, tidyr. data.table and reshape

Tags: r

I have a really huge data set, I share it by a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kc77cw1v5ofk6pt/m.tot3.csv?dl=0) because I don't know any other way of showing it to you in another way. I need that the file looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/em0pzt003zdqsr1/example.csv?dl=0). The second link is an example of the total file because it is really long to do it "by hand".

It hs been suggested to me to try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735239/arrange-a-complicated-data-set-in-r/62735835#62735835)
But it seems to me that my example in that post wasn't enough because with any of the proposals I am getting the result that I need. I've been trying for a week and I really don't know how to solve it, so I have decided to post my real data using a link in case that is more helpful. When I try Using `dplyr`
and `tidyr`I get this warning message

```
d<-read.csv("m.tot3.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",",dec=".")
df<-data.frame(d)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

sub1 <- df[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
sub2 <- df[c(FALSE, TRUE),]

tibble(ind = c(row(sub1)), col1 = factor(unlist(sub1), levels = letters[1:1688]), 
       col2 = as.integer(unlist(sub2))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2,
              values_fill = list(col2 = 0)) %>%
  select(-ind)
```

I get this error message

```
Error: Can't convert <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values in `col2` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
 Use `values_fn = list(col2 = list)` to suppress this warning.
 Use `values_fn = list(col2 = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
 Use `values_fn = list(col2 = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
```

Using `reshape`

```
sub1 <- df[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
sub2 <- df[c(FALSE, TRUE),]

out <- reshape(
  data.frame(ind = c(row(sub1)), 
             col1 = factor(unlist(sub1), levels = letters[1:1688]), 
             col2 = as.integer(unlist(sub2))),
  idvar = 'ind', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'col1')[-1]

names(out) <- sub("col2\\.", "", names(out))
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

I get this warning message

```
    Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  there are records with missing times, which will be dropped.
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for col1=NA: first taken`
```

finally, using `data.table`

```
 d_test<-melt(
   setDT(
    setnames(
      data.table::transpose(df), 
      paste(rep(1:(nrow(d)/2), each = 2), c("name", "value"), sep = "_"))),
  measure = patterns("name", "value"))[
    , dcast(.SD, variable ~ value1, value.var = "value2", fill = 0)]
```

I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/il067bz5dk1z5ec/test4.csv?dl=0)

I really don't know how to solve it and any answer is really welcome
Regards

Comment: Instead of a big data link, it is better to use `dput` of a small data.  Issue seems to be that there are duplicates and this causes the `pivot_wider` to create `list` column.  Here, we may need `tibble(ind = c(row(sub1)), col1 = factor(unlist(sub1), levels = letters[1:1688]), 
       col2 = as.integer(unlist(sub2)))  %>% mutate(rn = data.table::rowid(ind, col1))` before the `pivot_wider`

Comment: Based on the error, it seems that the duplicates coerc the pivot_wider to a list column.  To avoid, that you need to create a sequence column with `rowid` from `data.table` or a group by row_number

Comment: Looks like this is based on your previous question

Comment: yes it is, but I really can't solve it and the data set is really huge in order to handle it by hand

Comment: Can you try the suggested code in the comments

Comment: I have tested for duplicates using ``any(duplicated(d)) ```and i get ``
[1] FALSE``.

Comment: Using this``sub1 <- d[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
sub2 <- d[c(FALSE, TRUE),]

tibble(ind = c(row(sub1)), col1 = factor(unlist(sub1), levels = letters[1:1688]),
       col2 = as.integer(unlist(sub2))) %>% mutate(rn = data.table::rowid(ind, col1)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2,
              values_fill = list(col2 = 0)) %>%
  select(-ind)`` I get this `` rn  `NA`
   <int> <int>
 1     1     3
 2     1     4
 3     1     5
 4     1     9
 5     1     1``

Comment: I tried to read your data, it shows 12 observation and 1688 variables and all of them `character` class

Comment: Also, the `col1` values are all `NA` based on ` factor(unlist(sub1), levels = letters[1:1688])`.  It is because `levels` should match the values in 'sub1' it is not matching those

Comment: Yes is a metagenomic data and I have 6 samples and in each sample you can idenfy a lot of genus eg: 0asia,  0asia,  0fulsella,0fulsella, etc I need to order them in that way to use the ``vegan`` package

Comment: I have added the NAs because not all the observations have 1688 variables, some of them have a lower number of variables, the original spread sheet is really messy, with a lot of empty spaces

Comment: You can check my solution.  With the changes, it is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issue is that the `factor` conversion with `levels` return all `NA` because the `levels` are not matching with `unique` values in the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 <- tibble(ind = c(row(sub1)), 
       col1 = factor(unlist(sub1), levels = unique(unlist(sub1))), 
      col2 = as.integer(unlist(sub2)))
```

Second issue is there are duplicates, so we create a sequence column by 'col1'

```
out <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(col1)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2,
           values_fill = list(col2 = 0)) %>%
    select(-rn)

dim(out)
#[1]   23 3704


out[1:5, 1:5]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#    ind  `69`  `70`  `71`  `82`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     0     0     0
#2     2     0     4     0     0
#3     3     0     0     6     0
#4     4     0     0     0     8
#5     5     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I am getting this error ``Error: Column 3663 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.``

Comment: @Antonela I used your big dataset from the link and it is working for me.  Please check your dplyr/tidyr versions

Comment: It worked for me. Make sure `select` isn't being masked. You could use `dplyr::select` for example.